# How to compute $\int{\ln(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})dx}$?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

The integral I am trying to work out is

$$\int{\ln(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})dx}$$

So first step is substitute $u=x+1$:
$$\int{\ln(\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u})du}.$$

Now substitute $u=\cos^2(t)$.
$\int{-\ln(\sqrt{-\sin^2(t)}+\sqrt{\cos^2(t)})2\sin(t)\cos(t)dt}$. This works out to $\int{-\ln(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\sin(2t)dt}$. Remarkably, we obtain $\int{-\ln(e^{it})\sin(2t)dt}$ using Euler's identity.

Now we have $\int{-it\sin(2t)dt}$ and filling in reverse substitution $t=\arccos(\sqrt{x+1})$ after performing partial integration eventually yields me $0.5i\arccos(\sqrt{x+1})(2x+1)+0.5\sqrt{x^2+x}$.

I tried it on wolfram alpha and it gave a different result with hyperbolic functions. So that was not too useful to check this answer with. I feel this is not the right answer due to the imaginary inverse cosine factor. Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution not working with hyperbolic functions. Now updated with some more details.

Integrating by parts, and using that (by the chain rule, and writing the expression inside square brackets on common denominator)
$$
\begin{aligned}
D\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}}D\bigl(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}\bigr)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\Bigr]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}},
\end{aligned}
$$
we find that
$$
\int \log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})\,dx=x\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})-\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx
$$
Then, integrating by parts again, rewriting, splitting, and using the derivative on top,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx&=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}-\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\
&=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}-\int\frac{x+1}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx\\
&=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}-\int\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx-\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Moving the integral to the left-hand side, we find that
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}),
$$
and so, finally, one primitive is given by
$$
\int\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})\,dx = \Bigl(x+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\log(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}.
$$

Comment: Could you justify your first step, the fact, and your last step? I cant really follow them. But it seems like a nice solution!

Comment: I have now added some details on the differentiation. About the last step, I don't know what is the problem, so I don't know what to change...

Comment: Well I dont get what you mean with one primitive is given by

Comment: I only mean that to get all different primitives, one should add a constant.

Comment: Right i see, thanks man. I like your solution

Answer (score 4):

HINT...The integral is equivalent to $$I=\int\operatorname{arsinh} \sqrt{x}dx$$
Therefore it would make sense to deal with hyperbolic functions here. 
You could start with the substitution $$\sqrt{x}=\sinh u$$
This would give $$I=\int u\sinh 2udu$$
This can be done by parts.

Comment: Thanks, but honestly I am not familiar with hyperbolic functions yet...

Comment: Btw how do you get the large integral sign? I only get small ones

Comment: OK. What about trying the substitution $x=\tan^2\theta$? it's a bit messy but it works. For mathjax, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user209347: A quick way is to click the "edit" button and observe the differences.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, $u\ge 1$ in your integral (due to $\sqrt{u-1}$ present). So the substitution $u = \cos^2 t$ is not possible. However, you can use the hyperbolic substitution $u = \cosh t$ (of $x = \sinh t$ immediately) to get the same result as Walpha.

Comment: Wow that is a sharp observation! I guess that was the reason it did not work? But I can allow negative roots right, with the complex domain?

Comment: @user209347 Sometimes yes, you "can". But note that when making substitutions like the one you've made, you are changing the domain of integration to something very different, lying in the complex plain. That usually requires some additional reasoning.

Comment: So is the answer i got like an extension of walpha integral to the complex plane? That sounds weird but cool

Comment: Walpha is an awesome word to say out loud.

Comment: @user209347, something like this, yes.

Comment: @avid19: I've seen someone refer to it as Wolfie which gives it a canine appeal, but Walpha does have a nice ring to it.  :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, Walpha sounds like alpha wolf, very cool. Wolfie? Nah.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $$\sinh t =\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\text{, and } \cosh t =\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2} $$
Now note that \begin{align}
\cosh^2 t -\sinh^2 t&=\Big(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\Big)^2-\Big(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\Big)^2\\
&=\frac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}+2}{2^2}-\frac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2}{2^2}\\
&=\frac{2+2}{2^2}=1
\end{align}
Hence if in your integral you choose $x=\sinh ^2 t$ you get \begin{align}\sqrt x + \sqrt{x+1}&=\sinh t + \sqrt{\sinh^2t+1}\\
&=\sinh t + \sqrt{\cosh^2t}\\
&=\sinh t + \cosh t\\
&=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}+\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\\
&=e^t
\end{align}
.. this, hopefully, clarifies things for you.